# Re-insert branch to correct commit after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I started a new git repository, writing a lot of commits to master without realising it.

```
a --> b --> c --> d (master)
             \--> e (bar)
```

I realised that I wanted a simple baseline master, so I renamed my branch and created an orphan master with just the original readme in it.

```
git branch -m master foo
git checkout --orphan master
rm (everything but the readme)
git add -A
git commit -m "base"
```

And then I tried rebasing the two branches onto it

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
git checkout bar
git rebase master
```

However, what this produced was:

```
o (master) --> a --> b --> c --> d (foo)
          \--> a --> b --> c --> e (bar)
```

That's kind of obvious in hindsight, though it's not that neat. Given this state now, how can I re-insert the `bar` branch to the commit it originally branched from, removing the duplicated commits? (So it will look like the tree below).

```
o (master) --> a --> b --> c --> d (foo)
                            \--> e (bar)
```

Any advice on how to avoid this in the first place would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### How you got here

First, the fundamental problem: `git rebase` works by *copying* commits.  It therefore needs to know two things: *what to copy*, and *where to put the copies*.  The "where to put" is easier to see, especially when we draw graphs like you did (and I do below).

The way `git rebase` figures these things out by default is from a single argument, the one [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) calls the *upstream*.  In your case the upstream argument is `master`.

Here's your original graph again, redrawn in my preferred style:

```
a <- b <- c <- d   <-- master
           \
            -- e   <-- bar
```

Note that the arrows are all backwards.  This is on purpose, because Git insists on doing everything backwards. :-)  It does matter somewhat here, but usually I just leave out the interconnecting arrows entirely as they're more annoying than useful.  The most important part is the the branch *names* point to the branch *tips*, i.e., to the most recent commit.

Now, once you've made your *new* (orphan) master, and renamed the old one `foo`, the picture looks like this:

```
o            <-- master

a--b--c--d   <-- foo (HEAD)
       \
        e    <-- bar
```

You now run `git rebase master` while on branch `foo`.  The name `master` tells rebase *where to copy* (after the commit identified by `master`), and ...

The *what to copy* part is harder to see.  The argument `master` is actually treated as *what **not** to copy*.  Git will copy all the commits reachable from the current branch, i.e., `foo`, that are *not* reachable from the name `master`.  That means commits `a--b--c--d` are eligible for copying,<sup>1</sup> and `o` is excluded.  After copying, `git rebase` moves the label to point to the final copied commit.  Thus, once the copies are done, we get:

```
o               <-- master
 \
  a'-b'-c'-d'   <-- foo (HEAD)

a--b--c--d      [abandoned]
       \
        e       <-- bar
```

So, now that you know how `git rebase` picks *what to copy*, let's apply it to the new picture by moving `HEAD` to `bar` and doing `git rebase master`.  What are the eligible commits?  Start from `e` and work back to the left until you either run out, or hit commit `o` or a commit reachable by moving left from `o`, and you get `a--b--c--e`.  That's what `git rebase` will consider for copying, and the place it will copy them is "just after `o`", so we will get this:

```
  a''-b''-c''-e'   <-- bar
 /
o               <-- master
 \
  a'-b'-c'-d'   <-- foo

a--b--c--d      [abandoned]
       \
        e       [abandoned]
```

which is why you got what you got.

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "eligible" here only because they can still get excluded anyway, but in this case, they aren't: they go from "eligible" to "elected" every time.

---

#### How to fix it

Given that rebase copies commits, what we need is to copy `e` or `e'`—it doesn't really matter which one we copy since they're both the same except for their IDs—so that the new copy comes *after* `c'`.  That is, what we *want* is:

```
o               <-- master
 \
  a'-b'-c'-d'   <-- foo
         \
          e''   <-- bar
```

Since there is only one such commit, the easiest way is probably to just make a new `bar` branch-label pointing to `c'` and then `git cherry-pick` `e` or `e'`.  The easiest one to name is `e'` since the existing `bar` points to it:

```
git branch -m bar oopsbar  # move the name out of the way
git checkout -b bar foo^   # or foo~1, to name commit `c'`
git cherry-pick oopsbar    # copy e' to e''
```

We could also use `git rebase` here, and if there were more commits to copy, that would be the way to go, but let's move on to...

#### How to have avoided this originally

It's a bit painful, really.  The problem is that `git rebase` only works on *one* branch, namely the *current* branch.<sup>2</sup>  To do what you want, you must separate out the *what to copy* from the *where to put the copies*.  You do that by adding `--onto` to the `git rebase` command, and then changing the *upstream* argument:

```
git branch -m master foo   # as before
... and the same stuff to create the new master ...
# but this time:

git checkout foo
git rebase master      # copy a-b-c-d
git checkout bar       # and we already know there's one commit
git rebase --onto master bar~1 # copy bar~1..bar
```

The *upstream* argument, which is `bar~1` here, tells `git rebase` *what not to copy*.  We knew in advance there was one commit, so we could use `bar~1` to identify the first "stop" point.  What if we don't know how many?

Here's where it gets very difficult in general.  We must find a suitable "stop sign".  There's a symbolic one that works great *for this case*, which is to use `foo`'s *reflog*:

```
git rebase --onto master foo@{1}
```

because `foo@{1}` points to original commit `d` (take a look at the complete drawings), and commit `d` points back to commit `c`, which is the correct stop sign.

If we had more branches to copy, though, there might not be a single symbolic name that would find the right "stop point".  There is no built in solution in Git, other than manually identifying the proper stop-point commit and supplying it as a raw hash ID:

```
git rebase --onto master 7f3c9a82201ca9
```

or whatever.  That's quite ugly; Git needs some sort of "multirebase" command, that figures out these points for you, and runs multiple `git rebase` commands and allows you to abort the "outer multirebase" if needed.  Writing such a command is hard, though.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can give `git rebase` a branch-name to work on.  It checks out that branch, then proceeds to do all of the usual stuff on the current branch.  So it might *look like* it can run on other branches, but it's a cheap hack, and only works for one branch, and it really, literally does it by running `git checkout` anyway—which you could just do yourself.  (Rebase comes in several flavors and they are all shell scripts, driven from one initial script that does the `git checkout` if asked.)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of is to just rebase `bar` interactively (`-i`) onto `c` in foo's history and drop the duplicate commits.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git checkout foo                       # HEAD is now on d commit
$ git checkout -b bar-1                  # Checkout to new branch bar-1 with all commits (HEAD on d commit)
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1                # undo last commit (HEAD on c commit)

$ git checkout --orphan bar-clean        # checkout new bar-clean branch cleaning all commit history (HEAD on c commit)

$ git reflog                             # copy the commit-sha of e commit
$ git cherry-pick <e-commit-sha>         # take e commit, now HEAD is on e commit

$ git branch -D bar                      # delete previous bar branch
$ git checkout -b bar                    # create & checkout to new bar branch with only e commit
$ git branch -D bar-clean bar-1          # delete bar-clean & bar-1 branch
```

- Done. Now, your graph is like you want.

  ```
  o (master) --> a --> b --> c --> d (foo)
                              \--> e (bar)
  ```